# Simple Gridview and button problems. I am learning Asp.Net. Please help me out!

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I would not say I wasted my time, but spent around few hours changing this. But invain. Could some one please help me out. 
In the following code:

1. I need to use break in between Disable Location(Title) and the gridview
2. I want the border color of grid to none. I do not want any color.
3. I want both the buttons Disable or deactivate and Cancel to be displayed just below the gridview. and in the middle of the page.

Please help me out!! Thanks alot.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div style="display: block; background: url(images/reusable_blue_bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 -15px;
        border-left: #88b9c7 1px solid; border-bottom: #88b9c7 1px solid; border-top: #88b9c7 1px solid;
        border-right: #88b9c7 1px solid; padding: 0px 2px; height: 236px; min-height: 236px;
        height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
        <table align="center" style="width: 554px; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none;
            border-left-style: none; border-bottom-style: none" id="TABLE1">

            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="5" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px; margin: 0px;
                    font-family: Arial; color: #1e7c9b;">
                    Disable Location</td>
            </tr>
```

I need number 1 over here..

```
            <asp:GridView ID="disableloc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LocationName"
                DataSourceID="" AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="true" BorderStyle="None">
```

i want 2 over here, i guess

```
            </asp:GridView>
```

I want 3 in here..

```
            <tr align ="center" style="position:fixed">
               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDisable" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/images/green-deactivate.gif" OnClick="btnDisable_Click"
                    ValidationGroup="group1" />

               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />

            </tr>
         </table>

    </div>
```

Thankss so much!!

Comment: Can you post what isn't working?  (Less code more words!)

Comment: I did edited the code to make it easy. Thanks Nix!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use padding-bottom on the style of the header td to get the space between the header and the gridview.
2. Use gridlines="None" on the GridView.
3. Wrap both the GridView and  the buttons in tds, now they're directly in the tr and that's not exactly ok html so the button wind up in the top left corner of the table.