# Simple Gridview and button problems. I am learning Asp.Net. Please help me out!

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I would not say I wasted my time, but spent around few hours changing this. But in vain. Could some one please help me out.

In the following code:

1. I need to use break in between Disable Location(Title) and the gridview
2. I want the border color of grid to none. I do not want any color.
3. I want both the buttons Disable or deactivate and Cancel to be displayed just below the gridview. and in the middle of the page.

   ```
   <div style="display: block; background: url(images/reusable_blue_bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 -15px;
       border-left: #88b9c7 1px solid; border-bottom: #88b9c7 1px solid; border-top: #88b9c7 1px solid;
       border-right: #88b9c7 1px solid; padding: 0px 2px; height: 236px; min-height: 236px;
       height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
       <table align="center" style="width: 554px; border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none;
           border-left-style: none; border-bottom-style: none" id="TABLE1">

           <tr>
               <td align="center" colspan="5" style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px; margin: 0px;
                   font-family: Arial; color: #1e7c9b;">
                   Disable Location</td>
           </tr>
   ```

I need number 1 over here..

```
            <asp:GridView ID="disableloc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="LocationName"
                DataSourceID="" AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="true" BorderStyle="None">
```

i want 2 over here, i guess

```
            </asp:GridView>
```

I want 3 in here..

```
            <tr align ="center" style="position:fixed">
               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDisable" runat="server" ImageAlign="Middle" ImageUrl="~/images/green-deactivate.gif" OnClick="btnDisable_Click"
                    ValidationGroup="group1" />

               <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" />

            </tr>
         </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML as it is without breaking it up, might be easier to see how the page will look.

Comment: Sorry for that! I never realised! Will do that from now on. Will correct the previous ones as well. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple Gridview and button problems. I am learning Asp.Net. Please help me out!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449446/simple-gridview-and-button-problems-i-am-learning-asp-net-please-help-me-out)

Comment: the FAQ is at http://stackoverflow.com. Please read it. I'm sure that somewhere it says to not post duplicate questions (assuming that's not just common courtesy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use padding-bottom in the header td style to get the proper spacing.
2. Use gridlines="None" on the GridView.
3. Put the Gridview and the buttons in td:s to place them properly.

Comment: +1. Different interpretation of the question, good answers though.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather basic HTML/CSS knowledge (nothing wrong with that), but investigating basic information sources may help you help yourself.

As to your specific items:

- A 'break' can be as simple as a `<br />` statement between the controls
- if you don't want colors: `#88b9c7` and similar-looking statements are colors.
- As you're using a table, positioning the buttons below your grid can be done by placing them in the correct `<tr>` / `<td>`

Answer (score 0):

For #1, try using `margin` or `padding` on the `td`, or wrap "Disable Location" in a `span` (or something) and style its margin/padding to give some space.

For #2, try setting [`Gridlines="None"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.gridlines.aspx) on the GridView.

For #3, make sure you have a `<td>` inside the `<tr>`, and try using `text-align:center` on either the `td` or a `div` wrapping the buttons.  Alternatively, don't put it in the table, just wrap them in a div with `text-align:center`, right under the table (do you need the table at all?)